# How to select observations for a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have constructed a simple data frame with 4 observations and 4 variables. If I want to do a plot, that has only 2 of the observations, do I have to construct new data frame for it, or can I just pick Q1 and Q2 in the plot code?

Data and plot ↓

```
7L, 7L, 7L), mean = c(5.14285714285714, 5, 5.57142857142857, 
5.28571428571429), sd = c(0.899735410842437, 1.29099444873581, 
1.13389341902768, 0.951189731211342)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


ggplot(data, aes(x=question, y=mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd, ymax = mean+sd)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: You can use `ggplot(subset(data, test == TRUE), ...)` or at the layer level `geom_xyz(..., data = ~ subset(.x, test == TRUE))`. Replace `test == TRUE` with something else that results in a logical vector that can be used to subset the rows of your data.frame.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason I can't accept your answer even though it solved the problem. That "problem solved" icon is not visible for me this time